# How to convert pdf to docx in libreoffice 6.4?

Tags: docker, libreoffice, libreoffice-writer

I have libreoffice 6.4 installed in my ubuntu 18.04 container.

The goals is to convert a pdf file to docx.

I have already tried these commands :

```
libreoffice --headless --convert-to docx:"Microsoft Word 2007/2010/2013 XML" /pdf/pdf.pdf --outdir /pdf

libreoffice --headless --convert-to docx:"Microsoft Word 2007-2013 XML" /pdf/pdf.pdf --outdir /pdf

libreoffice --headless --convert-to docx:"MS Word 2007 XML" /pdf/pdf.pdf --outdir /pdf

libreoffice --headless --convert-to docx:writer_MS_Word_97 /pdf/pdf.pdf --outdir /pdf

libreoffice --headless --convert-to "docx:writer_MS_Word_2007" /pdf/pdf.pdf --outdir /pdf

libreoffice --headless --convert-to docx:writer_OOXML /pdf/pdf.pdf --outdir /pdf

libreoffice --headless --convert-to doc /pdf/pdf.pdf --outdir /pdf

libreoffice --headless --convert-to "docx:writer_MS_Word_2007" --outdir /pdf pdf.pdf
```

But they always return this message :

```
convert /pdf/pdf.pdf -> /pdf/pdf.docx using filter : writer_MS_Word_2007
Overwriting: /pdf/pdf.docx
Error: Please verify input parameters... (SfxBaseModel::impl_store <file:///pdf/pdf.docx> failed: 0x81a(Error Area:Io Class:Parameter Code:26))
```

Can anyone give me a clue on what's going on?

---

UPDATE :

I tried this command :

```
libreoffice --infilter="writer_pdf_import" --convert-to docx  --outdir /pdf /pdf/pdf.pdf
```

and it returned this message :

```
convert /pdf/pdf.pdf -> /pdf/pdf.docx using filter : Office Open XML Text
Overwriting: /pdf/pdf.docx
```

I can see it needs the `--infilter--` parameter, since the input file is a pdf.

But, it's using `Office Open XML Text` filter, I need to switch it to `Microsoft Word 2007-2013 XML`, how can I do that?

I already tried these and not working :

```
libreoffice --infilter="writer_pdf_import" --convert-to docx:"Microsoft Word 2007-2013 XML"  --outdir /pdf /pdf/pdf.pdf

libreoffice --infilter="writer_pdf_import" --convert-to "docx:Microsoft Word 2007-2013 XML"  --outdir /pdf /pdf/pdf.pdf

libreoffice --infilter="writer_pdf_import" --convert-to "docx:writer_MS_Word_2007"  --outdir /pdf /pdf/pdf.pdf

libreoffice --infilter="writer_pdf_import" --convert-to docx:"writer_MS_Word_2007"  --outdir /pdf /pdf/pdf.pdf

libreoffice --infilter="writer_pdf_import" --convert-to docx:writer_MS_Word_2007  --outdir /pdf /pdf/pdf.pdf
```

they always return this message (same as above) :

```
convert /pdf/pdf.pdf -> /pdf/pdf.docx using filter : writer_MS_Word_2007
Overwriting: /pdf/pdf.docx
Error: Please verify input parameters... (SfxBaseModel::impl_store <file:///pdf/pdf.docx> failed: 0x81a(Error Area:Io Class:Parameter Code:26))
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I finally figured out the workaround.

Hopefully, this will be useful for anyone having the same issues.

I did an experiment, by trying the possible word filters one by one from this [list](https://ask.libreoffice.org/upfiles/14478061067325683.ods), there are 4 successful attempts.

```
libreoffice --headless --infilter="writer_pdf_import" --convert-to docx  --outdir /pdf /pdf/pdf.pdf

libreoffice --headless --infilter='writer_pdf_import' --convert-to docx:"MS Word 2007 XML" --outdir /pdf /pdf/pdf.pdf

libreoffice --headless --infilter='writer_pdf_import' --convert-to doc:"MS Word 2007 XML" --outdir /pdf /pdf/pdf.pdf

libreoffice --headless --infilter="writer_pdf_import" --convert-to doc  --outdir /pdf /pdf/pdf.pdf
```

But between those 4 commands, the last one yields the best result, the converted document file content looks similar compared to the original one, FYI, my document has some chinese characters and tables, the first 3 commands didn't draw the table borders correctly, while the last one did.

---

UPDATE :

I decided to install libreoffice 7.0 on ubuntu 18.04 container.

To see the detailed list of filters, go [here](https://git.libreoffice.org/core/+/refs/heads/master/filter/source/config/fragments/filters), then open one of the xcu files, the filter details should be there, to use it, just pick from the name attribute, and use it like this :

```
libreoffice --headless --infilter='writer_pdf_import' --convert-to doc:"<enter_filter_name_here>" --outdir /pdf /pdf/pdf.pdf
```